# Property 'label' is missing in type 'string[]' but required in type - typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a type called Person like this :

```
type Person = {
  value?: string[];
  label?: string[];
};
```

I have this promise function

```
async function main(): Promise<Person> {
  const foo = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]).then(function (stuff) {
    var records = stuff.value
    
    const options = records?.map(d => ({
      "value" : d.name,
      "label" : d.name

    }))
    console.log(options)
    
    
  }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error)
  })
  
  return options
}
```

So I transform the api call into value and label (it is called options) and I need to pass this to a react component (in my return statement.

but I am getting the error

> Type 'string[]' has no properties in common with type 'Person'

when I hover over the 'return options' command .

Any idea how I can craft my promise better to avoid this error ?

Thanks !

Comment: `options` is a defined as a const inside the `Promise.then()` callback: the `options` you are returning is not the one you're updating it inside: their scopes are different. It likely refers to something else.

Comment: @Terry - thanks - can you shed some light on how I can write this promise correctly ?

Comment: It's really unsure why there is a need to use `.then()` when you're already using async/await. `const stuff = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"])` will do exactly what you need without creating an additional scope for `options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems strange to me like you're retrieving a *list* of person objects, which each have 1 label and 1 value. This is not consistent with the `Person` object you defined.

If this is the case, this could be written like this:

```
type Person = {
  value?: string;
  label?: string;
}

async function main(): Promise<Person> {
  const stuff = await dynamicsWebApi.retrieveAll("accounts",["name"]);
  const records = stuff.value;

  if (!records) {
    return [];
  }

  const options: Person[] = records.map(d => ({
      value: d.name,
      label: d.name
    }));
  
  return options;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice on this but it is still not working. I am getting an Type '{ value: any; label: any; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Person[]' on const options. and a no properties in common when we return it

Comment: the `records?.map ...` part indicates it can indeed be undefined. I've updated my answer to what would work. The reason it didn't work is that `options` is typed to be `Person[]` instead of `Person[] | undefined`. However, since now there is a check if `records !== undefined`, this will be fixed.